# Simplify Abs[]^2 everywhere from now on

Tags: functions

I would like Mathematica to Simplify all *further* expressions with `Abs[#]^2&` to `#^2&` is there a way i can do that?

Comment: /.Abs[x_]^2:>x^2

Comment: yes but then i need to do this replacement rule in every expression right? I would like somehow that Mathematica does this automatically. I would like something like: `Abs[#]^2&=#^2&`

Comment: You might try one of the `$Pre` values (`$Pre`,`$PreRead`,`$PrePrint`) e.g. `$Pre=(# /. Abs[x_]^2 :> x^2) &`. This applies your rule to every input expression. I admit I don't have much experience with these, so I can't comment on unintended consequences.

Comment: This is highly risky since `Abs[x]^2 == x^2` is only valid for real `x`. Since Mathematica generally operates in the complex plane, you are likely to generate problems. Specify real variables in `$Assumptions` and any function that accepts assumptions (e.g., `Simplify`) will make the simplification that you want for real values.

Comment: I cannot use `Simplify` since the expression is too lengthy. `Refine` doesn't work. Why not?

Comment: `Refine` takes the `Assumptions` option; did you specify all of the real variables or inequalities (e.g., `x > 0` implies that `x` is real)? Without a minimal working example (i.e., code) that demonstrates your problem it is difficult to troubleshoot. You must use `@<name>` to have an individual other than the poster to be notified of your comment.

Comment: @BobHanlon I thought this would work: `Refine[Abs[x]^2, x \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: Refine will work if you know that `x > 0` or `x < 0`; otherwise you need to use `Simplify`. If `Simplify` is too slow with the full expression you can try mapping `Simplify` onto the parts of the full expression. `Simplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] & /@ expr`

Comment: Have you tried to replace Abs by RealAbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done quite simply, but note the warnings below.

```
(* This works, but it is a bad idea: *)
Unprotect[Abs];
Abs /: Abs[x_]^k_ /; TrueQ[k == 2] := x^2;
Protect[Abs];

Abs[x]^2
```

> x^2

**Warnings**

Although this looks nice if you're used to working with real numbers, it's a bad idea. Here are a few examples of why:

```
Abs[x*I + 3]^2
```

> (x*I + 3)^2  (* This is clearly wrong *)

```
{Abs[x*I + 3]^2 /. x -> 2, (Abs[x*I + 3] /. x -> 2)^2}
```

> {5 + 12*I, 13} (* These should be the same *)

Additionally, it is very difficult to intuit where and how the Mathematica internals use rules like this to simplify things during calls to functions like `D`, `Simplify`, `Solve`, etc. It's likely that a call to `Integrate` will fail or be wrong after this rule is added because of some interaction happening in the Mathematica guts. In short: do this only if you know why and what you're doing; if you don't feel that there is an alternative, at least do it for a limited scope by using the `Block` form:

```
Block[
 {Abs},
 Abs /: Abs[x_]^k_ /; TrueQ[k == 2] := x^2;
 (* code here obeys the above rule *)
 Abs[x]^2]
```

> x^2

```
(* Code outside the Block uses the original Abs *)
Abs[x]^2
```

> Abs[x]^2

**Better**

A far better idea is to go with [Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon)'s comment/suggestions to correctly state your `$Assumptions` and use `Simplify` and `Refine`.

```
Block[
 {$Assumptions = Element[x, Reals]},
 Simplify[Abs[x]^2]]
```

> x^2